# How to set map language with swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

Various languages can be set inside the app, but the language displayed on the map does not change

I hope I can freely set the language of map display

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `language` key to your requests or follow [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=ru#languagesupport)

Comment: I use ios SDK, not http